# Youtube api v3 - how set the stream key on new event

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

i have few stream keys created in youtube studio

[image]

With this example code, i can create a new event, but it always create a new stream (called New Stream in this example) ,I wonder, how can I set/force to use a previous stream key (cam1profile for example)

The working code is from [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert) and just modified with my api keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution , just need to figure out the stream id I want to use and bind it to the broadcast

```
$stream_id='ls7ACzSkqopkYLg2N3ghmQ15498827578945';
$bindBroadcastResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->bind(
    $broadcastsResponse['id'],'id,contentDetails',
        array(
            'streamId' => $stream_id,
        ));
```